# How to use realm object server with Angularjs (or) Reactjs or any javascript frontend framework?

Tags: realm

I am building a chat application for University students so I have decided to work Realm instead of Firebase my only concern is where to view the database data ?

Can I use any MVC Front-end Framework like Angularjs or Reactjs to make a website which I can connect to Realm Object server and make mobile and Web App work AS-IS ?

Comment: Mobile part is easy. Web part is not.

Comment: There is an example using Node.js & express https://github.com/dalinaum/realm-blog this might be helpful.

Comment: @NabilHachicha A short readme file willl help a lot. BTW Thanks I shall look into it .

Comment: @NabilHachicha Sorry I have just gone through your tutorial folder in repo. Thanks a ton for such an beautiful documentation.